How can I have more than one parameter in navigationDestination
Still wrapping my head around the new SwiftUI Navigation... I find it interesting that most (if not all) examples on the web have navigationDestination with one parameter only, like this one from the official docs:
    NavigationStack {
        List(parks) { park in
            NavigationLink(park.name, value: park)
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Park.self) { park in // <-- here
            ParkDetails(park: park) // <-- and here
        }
    }

What if my ParkDetails accepts more than one param? Like if I need ParkDetails(park: park, updateThumbnail: true)? Is there a proven (and easy) way to do it? Should I use a touple (Park, Bool)?
Previously I used (and it worked flawlessly):
NavigationLink(destination: ParkDetails(park: park, updateThumbnail: true)) {
    //Link here
}

P.S. While I need only two parameters in my case, what if I needed 15 different params and some of them would be optional? Would I create a gazillion different .navigationDestination()'s?

Make a struct for the values you want to pass along

@loremipsum I understand what you mean. I considered this. One struct for my use case is probably fine. But if my app gets bigger I'll end up with lots of pointless structs that I keep for Navigation. I don't find that elegant =(

You could also consider an enum with an associated value. Each enum value (case) can have a different associated value, such as, a different type of struct.

What is the reason for updateThumbnail? That doesn't sound declarative, sounds like you are trying to do an action.

Store your additional info on the Navigation Enum
enum Park: Hashable {
  case park1(Bool) // updateThumbnail
}

Read about enum associated values here in the docs https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/enumerations/#Associated-Values

I see. This could be enum Destination: Hashable {     case park(park: ParkEntity, updateThumbnail: Bool)     case park(park: ParkEntity, updateThumbnail: Bool, thirdParam: String)     case country     //... }
